# Как правильно подключиться к базе данных в шаблоне MVC

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Доброго времени суток я создаю свой сайт с регистрацией, на системе MVC.

Как лучше реализовать подключение к базе данных?

Не хотелось бы в каждой функции класса **дублировать** создание класса

```
$pdo = new Pdo
```

и не хотелось бы делать **наследование** класса

```
class my class extends Pdo {}
```

Comment: Может вам обратиться к уже существующим фреймверкам, и посмотреть как это уже реализовано?

Comment: Mvc - это шаблон presentation layer. Единственное, что из него можно утверждать - это "подключаться к базе нужно в где-то в M"

Answer (score 1):

Вот что можно сделать. Чтобы не дублировать код инстанцирования, его надо поместить в метод.

```
function db() {
    return new PDO();
}
```

Отличный результат! Если теперь вам надо будет менять параметры подключения, вы сделаете это только в одном месте, а не по всему коду.

Едем дальше. Если вам нужно только одно подключение к базе, то можно сохранить его между вызовами.

```
function db() {
    static $pdo;

    if ($pdo === null) {
        $pdo = new PDO();
    }

    return $pdo;
}
```

Кийя! Теперь подключение будет создаваться только один раз. Знающие люди называют это реализацией шаблона Реестр (Registry).

Вообще для начала этого достаточно. Но со временем может обнаружиться, что `db()` вызывается по всему коду, где можно и где нельзя. Тогда вам понадобится совершить ещё один революционный шаг! Процесс передачи параметров в классы надо будет запрограммировать динамически. То есть, раньше у вас было `$model = new Model(db());`, а вы сделаете `$model = $registry->get(Model::class);`. Где `db()` во втором куске кода? А он должен быть запрятан в недрах конфигурации вашего `$registry`.

Я делаю это приблизительно так: создаю папку registry со скриптами, возвращающими инстансы всех нужных мне объектов. Рекурсивный код, подключающий эти скрипты проходит по всей цепочке зависимостей и отдаёт укомплектованный объект.

registry/Model.php

```
<?php

return RegistryItem::init(function(PDO $pdo) {
    return new Model($pdo);
})
->setArgsProvider(['db']);
```

registry/db.php

```
<?php

return RegistryItem::init(function() {
    static $pdo;

    if ($pdo === null) {
        $pdo = new PDO();
    }

    return $pdo;
});
```

Немного служебного кода и ваши контроллеры станут получать всё необходимое по массиву-описанию зависимостей.

Comment: Вроде неплохо. A как вы при этом каждый раз объясняете вашей IDE какой тип у результата вызова `$registry->get(Model::class);`?

Comment: @tutankhamun вот как у меня в примере registry/Model.php: код, который собирает аргументы ничего с ними не делает (на знает их тип), а код который аргументы получает их тип знает. То есть `$registry->get()` пишется не там, где нужна зависимость, а в служебном коде (один раз). Эта идея известна как внедрение зависимостей.